# Combine String in a Dictionary with Similar Key

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new Dictionary based on 3 others dictionary in my python data processing.

I have 3 Dictionaries, each with similar ID representing different section in the document.

For example

```
dict1 = {'001': 'Dog', '002': 'Cat', '003': 'Mouse'}
dict2 = {'001': 'Dog2', '002': 'Cat2', '003': 'Mouse2'}
dict3 = {'001': 'Dog3', '002': 'Cat3', '003': 'Mouse3'}
```

I wanted to combine all the values of similar key, therefore my desire output would like similar to this.

```
combineDict = {'001' : 'Dog Dog2 Dog3', '002' : 'Cat Cat2 Cat3', '003' : 'Mouse Mouse2 Mouse3'}
```

I did this

```
combineDict = {}
for k in dict1.keys():
    combineDict[k] = dict1[k] + " " + dict2[k] + " " + dict3[k]
```

However, the method above is super slow when dealing with large amount of text.

Is there anyway to write this function professionally to give the same result and lowered down the time it takes to process.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Are the three dictionaries going to always have the same length? Or can length differ?

Comment: same length and has exactly the same key

Comment: Is it always three dicts? Or arbitrary dictionaries?

Comment: @idjaw always 3 dicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep in line with your current approach, and specifically binding the following solution to the fact that you always have three equally length dictionaries, the approach is as such:

Iterate using one of the dictionaries, and create a new dictionary that will hold the values as a space separated string. The easiest way to do this is to collect them in a `list` and then use `" ".join`, which will give you the space separated list:

```
dict1 = {'001': 'Dog', '002': 'Cat', '003': 'Mouse'}
dict2 = {'001': 'Dog2', '002': 'Cat2', '003': 'Mouse2'}
dict3 = {'001': 'Dog3', '002': 'Cat3', '003': 'Mouse3'}


new_dict = {}

for key in dict1:
    new_dict[key] = " ".join([dict1[key], dict2[key], dict3[key]])
```

Output:

```
{'001': 'Dog Dog2 Dog3', '003': 'Mouse Mouse2 Mouse3', '002': 'Cat Cat2 Cat3'}
```

Or simply as a dictionary comprehension:

```
res = {k: " ".join([dict1[key], dict2[key], dict3[key]]) for k in dict1}
```

Comment: Thank you very much